# Select from a video stream all images separated by a given sampling interval OPENCV

Tags: video, opencv, sampling

I'm using OpenCV for a project, but am a total beginner.

I have a video file on my mass storage repository, and want to write a method to access all the frames of the video stream that are separated by a given sampling interval in input.

Videos can be in multiple formats (AVI – WMV – MPEG-2 – MPEG-4).

I was thinking that the method should work like this:

```
1. Have as input a desired sampling interval
2. Access the video at timestamp corresponding to the sampling interval
3. Save selected frame of video as an image
4. Go to next frame as determined from sampling frequency.
```

Can you please help me providing some code, or at least indications on a way to implement such a method with OpenCV methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at [VideoCapture::set](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-set) method and use CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC to get specific frames from the video file. Although I didn't tested this code, it would be something like this:

```
cv::VideoCapture vc(video_file_name);
cv::Mat frame;

//How you will get the interval is up to you
float interval = getInterval();
float cur_interval = 0;

while(1)
{
   vc.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, cur_interval);

   //The operator>> will return a NULL pointer if the next frame isn't valid
   if(vc >> frame)
     cv::imwrite("filename.jpg", frame);
   else
     break;

   cur_interval += interval;
}
```

Comment: there is just one thing I don't understand, how `VideoCapture::set` will save in the matrix `cv::Mat frame` the values corresponding to the particular time instant I saved in variable `cur_interval`? Looking at your code `vc.set()` seems completely decoupled from `cv::Mat frame`, and in the documentation of `VideoCapture::set` I couldn't find any reference to a matrix variable where it saves the frame. Can you please explain me how it's working?

Comment: vc.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, cur_interval) just sets the current timestamp of the VideoCapture. The line if(vc >> frame) is getting the first frame after that timestamp and saving to cv::Mat frame.

Comment: clear enough for me!thanks a lot..I'm trying it as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

Although OpenCV does wrap ffmpeg for video reading, ffmpeg is probably better suited to the task you describe.

You can get Zeranoe's Windows build [here](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) (assuming you're on Windows, if you're on Linux you probably know how to get access to it). If you just want to use the command-line version on Windows get the static build, otherwise get the development build.

[Here](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/) is Dranger's tutorial on getting started programming with the ffmpeg API.

You may be able to do this with a combination of ffmpeg and Python using [this tutorial](http://linuxers.org/tutorial/how-extract-images-video-using-ffmpeg) to extract all the frames.

HTH!